# Can't get python-social-auth to redirect to my custom urls after authentication

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I would like `python-social-auth` to redirect to `/?ref=twitter` if user logs in through twitter, and `/?ref=google` if they login through google-oauth2.

I installed the django version of the `python-social-auth` library using

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

So far, the authentication works, but `python-social-auth` always redirects to `/` (which is 'home').

Here are my settings:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

# Used to redirect the user once the auth process ended successfully. The value of ?next=/foo is used if it was present
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/?ref=twitter'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/?ref=google'

# URL where the user will be redirected in case of an error
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/?err=true'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/?ref=twitter&err=true'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/?ref=google&err=true'

# Is used as a fallback for LOGIN_ERROR_URL
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_LOGIN_URL = '/?ref=twitter'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL = '/?ref=google'

# Used to redirect new registered users, will be used in place of SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL if defined.
# Note that ?next=/foo is appended if present, if you want new users to go to next, you'll need to do it yourself.
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/?user=new'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/?ref=twitter&user=new'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/?ref=google&user=new'

# Like SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL but for new associated accounts (user is already logged in).
# Used in place of SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL = '/?assoc=true'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL = '/?ref=twitter&assoc=true'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL = '/?ref=google&assoc=true'
```

It would be extremely helpful if someone could point out what I am doing wrong here.

I am currently going through their [documentation](https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for clues.

Thanks